# search for identical segments in DNA sequence

Tags: python

I have the following formula:

> C=P<sub>1</sub>*4<sup>(n-1)</sup>+P<sub>2</sub>*4<sup>(n-2)</sup>+......+P<sub>i</sub>*4<sup>(n-i)</sup>+P<sub>n</sub>+1,

P can take one of this values `{'a','c','g','t'}`, and the value of `a is 0` , `c is 1` , `g is 2` and `t is 3` . For example my sequence is `s='act'`, i want to calculate C of this sequence , for this example

- P<sub>1</sub>=0,
- P<sub>2</sub>=1,
- P<sub>n</sub>=3.

So the result `C=8`.  My code looks like this:

```
def identicalSegment(): 
    for i in range(1,len(s)):
        if s[i]=='a': 
            p[i]=0 
        elif s[i]=='c': 
            p[i]=1 
        elif s[i]=='g': 
            p[i]=2 
        elif s[i]=='t': 
            p[i]=3 

    c=p[1]*4(pow(n-1))+p[2]*(pow(n-2))+p[n]+1 

    return c
```

I try to do this with python, but I'm having problems with the **if** statements.
Any ideas?

Comment: Show us some of your code

Comment: Does n represent the place in the list, or something else? A little more detail would help

Comment: def identicalSegment():

        for i in range(1,len(s)):

                if s[i]=='a':
                        p[i]=0
                        elif s[i]=='c':
                                p[i]=1
                                elif s[i]=='g':
                                        p[i]=2
                                        elif s[i]=='t':
                                                p[i]=3
                                                c=p[1]*4(pow(n-1))+p[2]*(pow(n-2))+p[n]+1
                                                return c

Comment: I've edited your answer to include the code - best to do it there rather than in the comments.  As far as I can tell though your code is incomplete - where are `n` and `p` defined? Also your first element looks at `p[1]`.  Is this meant to be `p[0]`? (Remember Python lists are zero indexed).   Also, how does this relate to your topic title?

Comment: the input is a DNA sequence and the out put is a number calculated from the formula.

Comment: the role of this formula is to transform a sequence to a set of integers

Comment: @will-hart n is the length of the list of input params, or characters. P represents some sort of temporary variable that the poster was attempting to use in order to do summation.

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid the ugly `if`s by using a dictionary like this:

```
code={'a':0,'c':1,'g':2,'t':3}
p=[code[i] for i in s]
```

Also note that in Python indices start at 0, not 1.

Finally, to calculate `c`, you should iterate over `p`. You need some work on that part of the code.

Comment: @m28 the fact that in the formula P starts with index 1 does not matter - the list `p` which you are using starts with index 0, so `p[1]` is the second member of `p`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Bitwise's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17634928/233608) answer to generate the `P` values, something like the following gives the expected result of `8`.

```
def identical_segment(input_string):

    # get the P values from the dictionary
    code = {"a": 0, "c": 1, "g": 2, "t": 3}
    p = [code[i] for i in input_string]

    # calculate length
    n = len(input_string)
    c = 0

    # calculate the score
    for i, n in enumerate(range(n, 0, -1)):
        c += p[i]*(4**(n - 1))

    # add one to the return value to account for the last digit
    return c + 1
```

Run in my Python terminal this gives:

```
>>> identical_segment("act")
... 8
```

Or

```
>>> identical_segment("gattaca")
... 9157
```

:)

Comment: thank you, but when i try to  run this code , i always have the same result 1

Comment: Are you passing your string into the function as per the examples? It will only return one for an empty string (as per your formula in your question - the +1 at the end)

Answer (score 0):

```
CODE_VALUES = {'a':0,'c':1,'g':2,'t':3}
MAGIC_VALUE_ONE = 4

def GetValues(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    for index, item in enumerate(lst):
        P = CODE_VALUES[item]
        multiplier = pow(MAGIC_VALUE_ONE, n - index - 1)
        yield P * multiplier

def CalculateSum(calc_string):
    return sum(GetValues(calc_string)) + 1

print CalculateSum('act')
```

Comment: thank you, if i want to apply this on a fasta file , what can I do?

Comment: Create another question for that, be specific with details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead a dict.

```
p = ['acgt'.find(i) for i in s]
```